# getOptions() for loop not working

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

The following code throws error. I try to get (alert) the value and options of an Optionset in MS CRM 2013, It successfully shows all the things but after that it shows error. i attached the screen shot that error

```
function GetOptionsetLable() 
{
    var OptionSetControl = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("test_613a");
    for(var intCounter=0;  OptionSetControl .getOptions().length; intCounter++)
    {
        var backendvalue=OptionSetControl .getOptions()[intCounter].value;
        alert(backendvalue.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetOptionsetLable() 
{
    var OptionSetControl = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("test_613a");
    for(var intCounter=0;  OptionSetControl .getOptions().length; intCounter++)
    {
        var backendvalue=OptionSetControl .getOptions()[intCounter].value;
        alert(backendvalue.toString());
    }
}
```

Your for loop will never end because you don't tell it when to stop.

```
OptionSetControl.getOptions().length
```

should be:

```
intCounter < OptionSetControl.getOptions().length
```

Full code:

```
function GetOptionsetLable() 
{
    var OptionSetControl = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("test_613a");
    for(var intCounter=0; intCounter < OptionSetControl.getOptions().length; intCounter++)
    {
        var backendvalue=OptionSetControl.getOptions()[intCounter].value;
        alert(backendvalue.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saravanakumar If my response solved your issue, please upvote and accept my answer. It rewards us both, as well as future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `value` property contains the optionset numeric value, and the `.text` property the label.

you can also use a shorter for condition:

```
var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("test_613a").getOptions();
for (var i in options) {
    alert(options[i].value);
}
```

I also created a library, you can find here:

[OptionSet JavaScript Helper Library](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/OptionSet-JavaScript-76af41f5)